# "Disconnect" forked Git repos in VSTS

Tags: azure-devops

In VSTS, I forked a repository to develop a separate product from the original repo.

When I make a PR from a branch into master in my forked repo, VSTS defaults to merging into the original repo. I have to be sure not to mistakenly merge into the original repo with every PR.
[image: VSTS new PR menu]

VSTS seems to think that I may want to merge changes from my forked repo into the original one. I have no plans to do so. How do tell VSTS to 'disconnect' my forked repo from the original?

Comment: If there's a better term for "Disconnect", I welcome someone to let me know. I mean to remove any connection between the two forked repos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there isn’t such feature in VSTS, there is the user voice that you can vote: [Allow option of converting forks to repos](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365802/allow-option-of-converting-forks-to-repos.html)

Answer (score 3):

## Work-around

As a work-around (in Visual Studio) until it's fixed:

1. **Pull** the *repo*.
2. **Delete the remote** *repo*.
3. **Create a new remote** *repo* with **the same name**.
4. **Push** the *repo*.

---

You might have to create a *temporary remote repo* (named *temp* if you'd like) in order to be able to delete the remote repo. You can delete the *temporary remote repo*, named "*temp*", after you've pushed to the new remote repo.

---

*You'll most-likely break anything (pull requests, work items) linked to the repo and also have to re-apply any policies and  security stuff.*

---

- repo = the faulty fork in VSTS.
- temporary remote repo = a temporary tepo created if you cant delete the fork repo.
- new remote repo = the new repo to be used instead of the fork.

Comment: I can only assume that would break every link to a commit/branch/PR in our work item tracking, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like one should disconnect the old remote origin and set the upstream before pushing. Maybe the push with the --set-upstream overwrites that?

Here's what I'm did:

1. git clone *ACCOUNT*@vs-ssh.visualstudio.com:v3/*ACCOUNT*/*PROJECT*/*FORK-NAME* *NEW-NAME*
2. git remote rm origin
3. Create the new repository on VSTS for *NEW-NAME*
4. git push --set-upstream *ACCOUNT*@vs-ssh.visualstudio.com:v3/*ACCOUNT*/*PROJECT*/*NEW-NAME* develop

This worked for me to change from a fork to a repo. I can see the full history and open changesets from the web viewer. I did this in Azure DevOps (formerly Visual Studio Team Services AKA VSTS). I did **not** test against GitHub.

Pull requests and pushes are lost. Commits are still linked

*I'm not sure if you need to do the push multiple times for different branches.* My fork only has a develop branch anyway. I only create a master branch so git flow doesn't complain.